# Let $H$ and $V$ be bounded self-adjoint operators. If $V$ is compact then $E_{H+V}(J)-E_{H}(J)$ is a compact operator.

Tags: operator-theory, spectral-theory, compact-operators, self-adjoint-operators

I read the following claim: Let $H$ and $V$ be  bounded self-adjoint operators. If $V$ is compact then $E_{H+V}(J)-E_{H}(J)$ is a compact operator for any Borel set $J \subseteq \mathbb{R}$. Here $E_A(\cdot)$ is the spectral measure of $A$. Can you help me to show it?

I think that if $E_{H+V}(J)-E_{H}(J)= E_{V}(J)$, then the claim will be true just because $V$ is compact. But I'm no sure if this equality holds, and I'm not sure $E_{H+V}(J)-E_{H}(J)$ is a projection.

Edit: J is assumed to be bounded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated, this is not true.

For instance on any infinite-dimensional Hilbert space,  take $H=0$ and $V$ an injective compact operator. Take $J=(0,\infty)$. Then $E_H(J)=0$, and $E_{H+V}(J)=E_V(J)=I$, which is not compact since it is an infinite projection.

Although in this example it is, there is no reason for $E_{H+V}(J)-E_H(J)$ to be a projection in general.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But in your example $H$ is not self-adjoint.

Comment: Fair enough. Please see the edit.

Comment: Thank you! I wonder if the claim is true for $J$ bounded. I'm going to edit my question.

Comment: Note that in my example you can replace $J$ for any interval $(0,c]$ as long as $c\geq\|V\|$.

Comment: You're right! Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome. Thinking about it, any infinite rank compact operator will have infinitely many eigenvalues in any interval $(0,\varepsilon)$, so it works for any $c>0$.